# Is there any way to generate a Test snippet based on a function in Rider?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, nunit, rider

I'm wondering if it's possible to generate a test according to a specified pattern in Rider.

For example i want to be able to (Alt + Enter in IntelliJ or Ctrl + . in VS) and then generate a test snippet based on that.

For example:

```
public async Task MyMethod() {}
```

Based on this method i want to generate something like this snippet:

```
[Test(Author = "My Name")]
public async Task MyMethod_Should...()
```

At the correct path and in the corrent project.

Is there anyway to do this out of the box or could i write some kind of plugin for it?

Comment: Take a look at [my blog post](https://mu88.github.io/2021/03/19/ReSharper-Templates.html) - maybe _Live Templates_ can help you with this